# Seemingly simple SQL query turns out quite complex (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I present here the simplified version of a problem I encountered, I work on Oracle 10.2:

I manage christmas gifts for kids, I have a list of kids, and a theoretical list of appropriate gifts depending on the kids age and sex. I also track the gifts they actually received:

```
    drop table actual_presents;
    drop table kids;
    drop table intended_presents;

    create table kids (
           name varchar2(30),
           sex varchar2(1), 
           constraint pk_kids primary key(name),
           constraint kids_sex_check check (sex in ('M', 'F'))
    );

    insert into kids(name, sex) values ('Alice','F');
    insert into kids(name, sex) values ('Bob','M');
    insert into kids(name, sex) values ('Carol','F');
    insert into kids(name, sex) values ('Dave','M');

    commit;

    create table intended_presents (
           age number,
           sex varchar2(1),
           present varchar2(30),
           constraint pk_intended_presents primary key(age, sex, present),
           constraint present_sex_check check (sex in ('M', 'F'))
    );

    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (5,'F', 'Doll');
    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (6,'F', 'Poney');
    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (5,'M', 'Car');
    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (6,'M', 'Soldier');

    commit;

    create table actual_presents (
           age number,
           kid varchar2(30),
           present varchar2(30),
           constraint pk_actual_presents primary key(age, kid, present),
           constraint fk_ap_k foreign key(kid) references kids(name)
    );

    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (5, 'Alice', 'Doll');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (6, 'Alice', 'Poney');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (5, 'Bob', 'Car');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (6, 'Bob', 'Soldier');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (5, 'Carol', 'Car');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (6, 'Carol', 'Poney');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (5, 'Dave', 'Soldier');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (6, 'Dave', 'Car');

    commit;
```

I now want extract the comparison between the expected and actual gifts for each kid. As long as each kid receives only 1 gift, it's easy:

```
    select 'Basic query: double join, works well with 1 present per christmas' as remark from dual;
    select k.name, k.sex, ip.age, ip.present as intended_present, ap.present as actual_present
    from kids k, intended_presents ip, actual_presents ap
    where k.name = ap.kid
    and k.sex = ip.sex
    and ap.age = ip.age
    order by k.name, ip.age, ip.present;
```

But there are more complex cases: we can schedule several gifts for a given christmas, or a kid who should receive 2 gifts might actually get 1 or 3.

```
    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (5,'F', 'Drum');
    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (6,'F', 'Orange');
    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (5,'M', 'Itchy sweater');
    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (6,'M', 'Coloring book');        
    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (7,'M', 'Trumpet');
    insert into intended_presents(age, sex, present) values (7,'M', 'Apple');

    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (5, 'Alice', 'Drum');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (6, 'Alice', 'Orange');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (5, 'Bob', 'Itchy sweater');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (6, 'Bob', 'Coloring book');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (5, 'Carol', 'Trumpet');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (5, 'Dave', 'Coloring book');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (6, 'Dave', 'Itchy sweater');
    insert into actual_presents(age, kid, present) values (6, 'Dave', 'Puppy');
```

Now I find it impossible to make a query / view that would return the following expected result:

```
    NAME                   S    AGE ACTUAL_PRESENT         INTENDED_PRESENT
    ------------------------------ - ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
    Alice                  F      5 Doll               Doll
    Alice                  F      5 Drum               Drum
    Alice                  F      6 Orange             Orange
    Alice                  F      6 Poney              Poney
    Bob                M      5 Car                Car
    Bob                M      5 Itchy sweater          Itchy sweater
    Bob                M      6 Coloring book          Coloring book
    Bob                M      6 Soldier            Soldier
    Carol                  F      5 Car                Doll
    Carol                  F      5 Trumpet            Drum
    Carol                  F      6                Orange
    Carol                  F      6 Poney              Poney
    Dave                   M      5 Coloring book          Car
    Dave                   M      5 Soldier            Itchy sweater
    Dave                   M      6 Car                Coloring book
    Dave                   M      6 Itchy sweater          Soldier
    Dave                   M      6 Puppy

    17 rows selected.
```

The 'simple' query described before will return extra unwanted rows, because the join is no longer complete with several gifts (E.g. 1 correct row for Alice 5 Doll Doll, 1 incorrect for Alice 5 Doll Drum).

The closest I got to a valid result was using some trick by ranking the rows, then trying to extract only the correct ones, but still not good for the intended presents column:

```
    select 'score + partition by rank' as remark from dual;
    select name, sex, age, actual_present, intended_present from (
           select name, sex, age, actual_present, intended_present, row_number() over (partition by name, sex, age, actual_present order by score desc) as rank
           from (
                select 
                (case when sq.actual_present = ip.present then 1
                else 0
                end) as score,
                sq.name as name, nvl(sq.sex, ip.sex) as sex, nvl(sq.age, ip.age) as age, sq.actual_present, ip.present as intended_present
                from (
                     select k.name, k.sex, ap.age, ap.present as actual_present
                     from kids k,actual_presents ap
                     where k.name = ap.kid
                ) sq
                full outer join intended_presents ip
                on ip.age = sq.age
                and ip.sex = sq.sex
                where name is not null
                )
    ) where rank = 1
    order by name, age, actual_present;

    NAME                   S    AGE ACTUAL_PRESENT         INTENDED_PRESENT
    ------------------------------ - ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
    Alice                  F      5 Doll               Doll
    Alice                  F      5 Drum               Drum
    Alice                  F      6 Orange             Orange
    Alice                  F      6 Poney              Poney
    Bob                M      5 Car                Car
    Bob                M      5 Itchy sweater          Itchy sweater
    Bob                M      6 Coloring book          Coloring book
    Bob                M      6 Soldier            Soldier
    Carol                  F      5 Car                Doll
    Carol                  F      5 Trumpet            *Doll*
    Carol                  F      6 Poney              Poney
    Dave                   M      5 Coloring book          Car
    Dave                   M      5 Soldier            *Car*
    Dave                   M      6 Car                Coloring book
    Dave                   M      6 Itchy sweater          *Coloring book*
    Dave                   M      6 Puppy              *Coloring book*

    16 rows selected.
```

I tried adding an extra column present_index to make the join natural, but this does not solve the problem because:
- it is an unwanted change of the datamodel only for this view
- it does not accurately describe reality (1 - Doll + 2 - Drum is equivalent to 1 - Drum + 2 - Doll)
- we are missing lines for extra gifts (Dave - 6 - Puppy - NULL)

```
    alter table intended_presents add present_index number;
    update intended_presents set present_index = 1 where present in ('Doll', 'Car', 'Orange', 'Soldier', 'Apple');
    update intended_presents set present_index = 2 where present_index is null;
    commit;

    alter table intended_presents drop constraint pk_intended_presents;
    alter table intended_presents add constraint pk_intended_presents primary key(age, sex, present_index);
    select * from intended_presents order by age, sex, present_index;

    alter table actual_presents add present_index number;
    update actual_presents set present_index = 1 where present in ('Doll', 'Car', 'Orange', 'Soldier');
    update actual_presents set present_index = 3 where present in ('Puppy');
    update actual_presents set present_index = 2 where present_index is null;
    commit;
    alter table actual_presents drop constraint pk_actual_presents;
    alter table actual_presents add constraint pk_actual_presents primary key(age, kid, present_index);

    select 'With present_index, we can use that in the join.' as remark from dual;
    select k.name, k.sex, ip.age, ip.present as intended_present, ap.present as actual_present, ap.present_index
    from kids k, intended_presents ip, actual_presents ap
    where k.name = ap.kid
    and k.sex = ip.sex
    and ap.age = ip.age
    and ap.present_index = ip.present_index
    order by k.name, ip.age, ap.present_index;

    NAME                   S    AGE INTENDED_PRESENT           ACTUAL_PRESENT         PRESENT_INDEX
    ------------------------------ - ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------
    Alice                  F      5 Doll               Doll                       1
    Alice                  F      5 Drum               Drum                       2
    Alice                  F      6 Orange             Orange                     1
    Alice                  F      6 Poney              Poney                      2
    Bob                M      5 Car                Car                        1
    Bob                M      5 Itchy sweater          Itchy sweater                  2
    Bob                M      6 Soldier            Soldier                    1
    Bob                M      6 Coloring book          Coloring book                  2
    Carol                  F      5 Doll               Car                        1
    Carol                  F      5 Drum               Trumpet                    2
    Carol                  F      6 Poney              Poney                      2
    Dave                   M      5 Car                Soldier                    1
    Dave                   M      5 Itchy sweater          Coloring book                  2
    Dave                   M      6 Soldier            Car                        1
    Dave                   M      6 Coloring book          Itchy sweater                  2

    15 rows selected.


    update actual_presents set present_index = 3 where kid = 'Alice' and present = 'Doll'; 
    update actual_presents set present_index = 1 where kid = 'Alice' and present = 'Drum'; 
    update actual_presents set present_index = 2 where kid = 'Alice' and present = 'Doll'; 
    commit;

    select k.name, k.sex, ip.age, ip.present as intended_present, ap.present as actual_present, ap.present_index
    from kids k, intended_presents ip, actual_presents ap
    where k.name = ap.kid
    and k.sex = ip.sex
    and ap.age = ip.age
    and ap.present_index = ip.present_index
    order by k.name, ip.age, ap.present_index;

    NAME                   S    AGE INTENDED_PRESENT           ACTUAL_PRESENT         PRESENT_INDEX
    ------------------------------ - ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------
    Alice                  F      5 *Doll*             *Drum*                     1
    Alice                  F      5 *Drum*             *Doll*                     2
    Alice                  F      6 Orange             Orange                     1
    Alice                  F      6 Poney              Poney                      2
    Bob                M      5 Car                Car                        1
    Bob                M      5 Itchy sweater          Itchy sweater                  2
    Bob                M      6 Soldier            Soldier                    1
    Bob                M      6 Coloring book          Coloring book                  2
    Carol                  F      5 Doll               Car                        1
    Carol                  F      5 Drum               Trumpet                    2
    Carol                  F      6 Poney              Poney                      2
    Dave                   M      5 Car                Soldier                    1
    Dave                   M      5 Itchy sweater          Coloring book                  2
    Dave                   M      6 Soldier            Car                        1
    Dave                   M      6 Coloring book          Itchy sweater                  2

    15 rows selected.
```

In the end, I only managed to create a view from a package-based pipelined function which actually computes the wanted values with back tracking (i can post the code, if wanted).
That seems really complex and costly for this simple problem with 3 little tables. Am I missing something obvious here ?

***************** Solution by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3486433/serpiton *****************

Your query perfectly shows all the discrepencies, all I have to do now is to add the lines where actual = intended and my problem is solved

```
    WITH ActualNotIntended AS (
      SELECT name, age, sex, present as actual
           ,  Row_Number() OVER (Partition BY name, age ORDER BY present) as ID
      FROM   (SELECT k.name, a.age, k.sex, a.present
              FROM   kids k
                     INNER JOIN actual_presents a ON k.Name = a.kid
              MINUS
              SELECT k.name, i.age, k.sex, i.present
              FROM   kids k
                     INNER JOIN intended_presents i ON k.sex = i.sex) a
    ), IntendedNotActual AS (
      SELECT name, age, sex, present as intended
           ,  Row_Number() OVER (Partition BY name, age ORDER BY present) as ID
      FROM   (SELECT k.name, i.age, k.sex, i.present
              FROM   kids k
                     INNER JOIN intended_presents i ON k.sex = i.sex
                     INNER JOIN actual_presents a ON a.age = i.age AND k.sex = i.sex
              MINUS
              SELECT k.name, a.age, k.sex, a.present
              FROM   kids k
                     INNER JOIN actual_presents a ON k.Name = a.kid) i
    ), ActualIntended as(
              SELECT k.name, a.age, k.sex, a.present as actual, i.present as intended
              FROM kids k 
              JOIN actual_presents a ON k.name = a.kid
              JOIN intended_presents i ON k.sex = i.sex AND i.age = a.age AND i.present = a.present
    )
    SELECT Coalesce(a.name, i.name) as name
         , Coalesce(a.age, i.age) as age
         , Coalesce(a.sex, i.sex) as sex
         , actual
         , intended
    FROM   ActualNotIntended a
           FULL JOIN IntendedNotActual i 
           ON a.name = i.name AND a.age = i.age 
           AND a.sex = i.sex AND a.id = i.id
    UNION 
    SELECT name, age, sex, actual, intended
    FROM ActualIntended
    ORDER by name, age, actual;

    NAME                      AGE S ACTUAL             INTENDED
    ------------------------------ ---------- - ------------------------------ ------------------------------
    Alice                   5 F Doll               Doll
    Alice                   5 F Drum               Drum
    Alice                   6 F Orange             Orange
    Alice                   6 F Poney              Poney
    Bob                 5 M Car                Car
    Bob                 5 M Itchy sweater          Itchy sweater
    Bob                 6 M Coloring book          Coloring book
    Bob                 6 M Soldier            Soldier
    Carol                   5 F Car                Doll
    Carol                   5 F Trumpet            Drum
    Carol                   6 F Poney              Poney

    NAME                      AGE S ACTUAL             INTENDED
    ------------------------------ ---------- - ------------------------------ ------------------------------
    Carol                   6 F                Orange
    Dave                    5 M Coloring book          Car
    Dave                    5 M Soldier            Itchy sweater
    Dave                    6 M Car                Coloring book
    Dave                    6 M Itchy sweater          Soldier
    Dave                    6 M Puppy

    17 rows selected.
```

For the record, this is much simpler, readable and maintainable that the function based view I was going for:

```
    DROP TYPE V_RECORD_TABLE;
    DROP TYPE V_RECORD;
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE V_RECORD AS OBJECT (
        NAME             VARCHAR2(30),
        SEX              VARCHAR2(1),
        AGE              NUMBER,
        ACTUAL_PRESENT   VARCHAR2(30),
        INTENDED_PRESENT VARCHAR2(30) 
        );
    /
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE V_RECORD_TABLE AS TABLE OF V_RECORD;
    /


    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE INTENDED_VS_ACTUAL AS 
      FUNCTION GET_DATA RETURN V_RECORD_TABLE PIPELINED;
    END INTENDED_VS_ACTUAL;
    /

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY INTENDED_VS_ACTUAL AS

      TYPE REF_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
      /* types to record intended presents */
      TYPE LIST_OF_IP_REC IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
      TYPE LIST_OF_IP_PER_AGE IS TABLE OF LIST_OF_IP_REC INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; /* index per age */
      TYPE LIST_OF_IP IS TABLE OF LIST_OF_IP_PER_AGE INDEX BY VARCHAR2(1);  /* index per sex */

      TYPE EXPECTED_USED IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);


    FUNCTION TREAT_PENDING(PENDING_ACTUAL IN OUT LIST_OF_IP_REC, EXP_USED IN OUT EXPECTED_USED, CUR_KID IN VARCHAR2, CUR_AGE IN NUMBER, CUR_SEX VARCHAR2) RETURN V_RECORD_TABLE 
      IS 
      CUR_EXPECTED VARCHAR2(30) := '';
      CUR_EXPECTED_SELECTED VARCHAR2(30) := '';  
      V_REC V_RECORD_TABLE := V_RECORD_TABLE();
      BEGIN
          IF PENDING_ACTUAL.LAST > 0 THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('pending actual has '||PENDING_ACTUAL.LAST||' items');
             FOR i IN PENDING_ACTUAL.FIRST .. PENDING_ACTUAL.LAST
             LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('pending actual '||PENDING_ACTUAL(i));
                CUR_EXPECTED_SELECTED := NULL;
                CUR_EXPECTED := EXP_USED.FIRST;
                WHILE CUR_EXPECTED IS NOT NULL
                LOOP
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('checking exp used item '||CUR_EXPECTED||' with value '||EXP_USED(CUR_EXPECTED));
                    IF EXP_USED(CUR_EXPECTED) = 0 THEN
                       EXP_USED(CUR_EXPECTED) := 1;
                       CUR_EXPECTED_SELECTED := CUR_EXPECTED;
                    END IF;
                    EXIT WHEN CUR_EXPECTED_SELECTED IS NOT NULL;
                    CUR_EXPECTED := EXP_USED.NEXT(CUR_EXPECTED);
                END LOOP; -- loop on expected used
                IF CUR_EXPECTED_SELECTED IS NOT NULL THEN 
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('returning row with actual '||PENDING_ACTUAL(i)||' exp used selected '||CUR_EXPECTED_SELECTED);
                   V_REC.EXTEND;
                   V_REC(V_REC.LAST) := V_RECORD(CUR_KID, CUR_SEX, CUR_AGE, PENDING_ACTUAL(i), CUR_EXPECTED_SELECTED);       
                ELSE
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('returning row with actual '||PENDING_ACTUAL(i)||' exp used selected NULL');
                   V_REC.EXTEND;
                   V_REC(V_REC.LAST) := V_RECORD(CUR_KID, CUR_SEX, CUR_AGE, PENDING_ACTUAL(i), NULL);       
                END IF;
             END LOOP; -- loop on pending actual
          END IF;     -- if pending actual

          /* remaining unused expected */
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('checking remaining unused expected');
          CUR_EXPECTED := EXP_USED.FIRST;
          WHILE CUR_EXPECTED IS NOT NULL
          LOOP
    --        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('checking exp used item '||CUR_EXPECTED||' with value '||EXP_USED(CUR_EXPECTED));
            IF EXP_USED(CUR_EXPECTED) = 0 THEN
               EXP_USED(CUR_EXPECTED) := 1;
               V_REC.EXTEND;
               V_REC(V_REC.LAST) := V_RECORD(CUR_KID, CUR_SEX, CUR_AGE, NULL, CUR_EXPECTED);       
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('returning row with actual NULL exp used selected '||CUR_EXPECTED);
            END IF;
            CUR_EXPECTED := EXP_USED.NEXT(CUR_EXPECTED);
          END LOOP; -- loop on expected used
          RETURN V_REC;
      END TREAT_PENDING;


      FUNCTION GET_DATA RETURN V_RECORD_TABLE 
      PIPELINED
      IS
      V_REC V_RECORD_TABLE;

      /* variables to fetch records */
      CUR REF_CURSOR;
      CUR_SEX     VARCHAR2(1);
      CUR_AGE     NUMBER;
      CUR_PRESENT VARCHAR2(30);
      CUR_KID     VARCHAR2(30);
      IP_LIST LIST_OF_IP;
      /* TREATMENT VARS */
      PREV_KID VARCHAR2(30) := '';
      PREV_AGE NUMBER := -1;
      PREV_SEX VARCHAR2(1) := '';

      i NUMBER;
      PENDING_ACTUAL LIST_OF_IP_REC := LIST_OF_IP_REC();

      EXP_USED EXPECTED_USED;
      AP_FOUND BOOLEAN := FALSE;
      BEGIN
      /* first record intended presents by age, sex */
      OPEN CUR FOR SELECT SEX, AGE, PRESENT FROM INTENDED_PRESENTS;
      LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO cur_sex, cur_age, cur_present;
        EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
        IF NOT IP_LIST.EXISTS(CUR_SEX) THEN
           IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE) := LIST_OF_IP_REC();
        END IF;
        IF NOT IP_LIST(CUR_SEX).EXISTS(CUR_AGE) THEN
           IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE) := LIST_OF_IP_REC();
        END IF;
        IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE).EXTEND;
        IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE)(IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE).LAST) := CUR_PRESENT;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE CUR;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('intended presents recorded');

      /* Treat actual presents */
      OPEN CUR FOR SELECT K.NAME, K.SEX, AP.AGE, AP.PRESENT AS ACTUAL_PRESENT 
                   FROM KIDS K, ACTUAL_PRESENTS AP 
                   WHERE K.NAME = AP.KID ORDER BY K.NAME, AP.AGE;
      LOOP
        FETCH CUR INTO CUR_KID, CUR_SEX, CUR_AGE, CUR_PRESENT;
        EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('********** actual present record kid '||CUR_KID||' sex '||CUR_SEX||' age '||CUR_AGE||' present '||CUR_PRESENT||' *********');
        IF NOT IP_LIST.EXISTS(CUR_SEX) THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-1, 'unknown sex '||CUR_SEX);
        END IF;
        IF NOT IP_LIST(CUR_SEX).EXISTS(CUR_AGE) THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2, 'unknown age for sex '||CUR_SEX||': '||CUR_AGE);
        END IF;

        IF (CUR_KID <> PREV_KID OR CUR_AGE <> PREV_AGE) THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('switching kid or age, from '||PREV_KID||'/'||PREV_AGE||' to '||CUR_KID||'/'||CUR_AGE);
          IF PREV_AGE > -1 THEN
             /* here send rows from collected data */
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checking for pending records...');
             V_REC := TREAT_PENDING(PENDING_ACTUAL, EXP_USED, PREV_KID, PREV_AGE, PREV_SEX);                                        
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found records to return: '||V_REC.LAST);
             IF V_REC.LAST IS NOT NULL THEN
                FOR i IN V_REC.FIRST .. V_REC.LAST
                LOOP
                   PIPE ROW ( V_REC(i));
                END LOOP;
             END IF;
          END IF;     -- if prev_age > 1 i.e. had something before, to ensure not executed on first row

          /* here reinit variables */
          PENDING_ACTUAL.DELETE;
          EXP_USED.DELETE;
        END IF; -- if switch kid / age
        PREV_KID := CUR_KID;
        PREV_AGE := CUR_AGE;    
        PREV_SEX := CUR_SEX;
        /* Check whether actual present has been returned, store in pending list if not */
        AP_FOUND := FALSE;
        FOR i IN IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE).FIRST .. IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE).LAST
        LOOP
          IF CUR_PRESENT = IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE)(i) THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('match found for '||CUR_PRESENT||' at index '||i||' marking '||IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE)(i)||' as used');
            EXP_USED(IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE)(i)) := 1;
            PIPE ROW ( V_RECORD( CUR_KID, CUR_SEX, CUR_AGE, CUR_PRESENT, IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE)(i) ) );
            AP_FOUND := TRUE;
          ELSE
            IF NOT EXP_USED.EXISTS(IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE)(i)) THEN
              EXP_USED(IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE)(i)) := 0;
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(IP_LIST(CUR_SEX)(CUR_AGE)(i)||' marked as not used');
            END IF;
          END IF;
        END LOOP; -- loop of intended presents
        IF NOT AP_FOUND THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no match found for '||CUR_PRESENT||' in intended list. storing in pending_actual');
          PENDING_ACTUAL.EXTEND;
          PENDING_ACTUAL(PENDING_ACTUAL.LAST) := cur_present;
        END IF;


      END LOOP; -- loop on actual presents from query

      V_REC := TREAT_PENDING(PENDING_ACTUAL, EXP_USED, CUR_KID, CUR_AGE, CUR_SEX); -- treat remaining data for last kid/age group of rows
      IF V_REC.LAST IS NOT NULL THEN
         FOR i IN V_REC.FIRST .. V_REC.LAST
         LOOP
            PIPE ROW ( V_REC(i));
         END LOOP;
      END IF;

      RETURN;
      END GET_DATA;

    END INTENDED_VS_ACTUAL;
    /


    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_INTENDED_VS_ACTUAL AS SELECT * FROM TABLE(INTENDED_VS_ACTUAL.GET_DATA());
    SELECT * FROM V_INTENDED_VS_ACTUAL ORDER BY NAME, AGE, ACTUAL_PRESENT;

    NAME                   S    AGE ACTUAL_PRESENT         INTENDED_PRESENT
    ------------------------------ - ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
    Alice                  F      5 Doll               Doll
    Alice                  F      5 Drum               Drum
    Alice                  F      6 Orange             Orange
    Alice                  F      6 Poney              Poney
    Bob                M      5 Car                Car
    Bob                M      5 Itchy sweater          Itchy sweater
    Bob                M      6 Coloring book          Coloring book
    Bob                M      6 Soldier            Soldier
    Carol                  F      5 Car                Doll
    Carol                  F      5 Trumpet            Drum
    Carol                  F      6 Poney              Poney
    Carol                  F      6                Orange
    Dave                   M      5 Coloring book          Car
    Dave                   M      5 Soldier            Itchy sweater
    Dave                   M      6 Car                Soldier
    Dave                   M      6 Itchy sweater          Coloring book
    Dave                   M      6 Puppy
```

Comment: I need more coffee ...

Comment: You don't really store age, do you?

Comment: This is actually a very simplified version of the problem I'm dealing with, the first "simple query" I'm mentioning is more than 100 lines in real conditions. I don't store age in KIDS, but that would not change anything since I need the full history.

Comment: I think you are struggling with a good concept rather than with how to write a query. What do you actually want to show? Dave got Soldier and Coloring Book instead of Car and Itchy Sweater at the age of 5. He did not get the Soldier instead of the Car and the Coloring Book instead of the Itchy Sweater. I would recommend three result columns, each holding a comma-separated list: 1. Got as expected (nothing in this case), 2. Got unexpected ('Coloring Book, Soldier'), 3. Not got though expected ('Car, Itchy Sweater'). [to be continued]

Comment: Now we know that Santa Claus uses Oracle

Comment: ... Then: What rows shall your result list contain? One row per name? One per age and sex? One per name and age?

Comment: Did you keep a list of the 'intended presents' you were going to give an individual child. Currently, your 'intended presents' represent a pool of all possible 'intended_presents; for a child by gender.

Comment: In my result set, 'Dave got Coloring book instead of Car' and 'Dave got Coloring book instead of Itchy sweater' would be equivalent. I need to be sure that when the intended / actual match, they should belong in the same row. I want to be able to see directly in the view any discrepency between intended and actual presents, so I could query on intended_present != actual_present, and be sure that these are discrepencies.

Comment: Ryan, intended_present is not really a pool of all possible, it means the kid should receive EVERY matching present, no more or no less

Comment: If you create an ERD of your tables, you will see that you have a fan trap. kids joined to actual presents is a 1 to many join and kids to intended_presents is really a many to many join (bad). The expected outcome should be n x m (with that bad many to many join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a system to model that problem with Oracle, in TSQL, using almost only standard SQL the model can be

```
SELECT k.name, a.age, k.sex, a.present actual
     , Coalesce(i.present, i2.present) intended
FROM   kids k
       INNER JOIN actual_presents a ON k.Name = a.kid
       FULL  JOIN intended_presents i ON a.age = i.age AND k.sex = i.sex 
                                     AND a.present = i.present
       INNER JOIN intended_presents i2 ON a.age = i2.age AND k.sex = i2.sex
WHERE  k.name IS NOT NULL
  AND  (i2.Present = a.present OR i.Present IS NULL)
ORDER BY k.name, a.age
```

- The `FULL JOIN` compare the actual and inteded present
- The `INNER JOIN` pick the intended present for the age and sex of the kid
- The `(i2.Present = a.present OR i.Present IS NULL)` condition removes the duplicate line if the actual gifts is the inteded one.

The line duplication remains when the actual and inteded gifts don't match, but that can probably be solved using `LISTAGG` grouping for all the field except `intended`.

**Gettin only the difference**
From one of the last comment from the OP it seems that the final use for the view will be to see the discrepancies from the actual and inteded gifts, in that case maybe the middle passage can be skipped to get the final result right away

```
WITH ActualNotIntended AS (
  SELECT name, age, sex, present actual
       , ID = Row_Number() OVER (Partition BY name, age ORDER BY present)
  FROM   (SELECT k.name, a.age, k.sex, a.present
          FROM   kids k
                 INNER JOIN actual_presents a ON k.Name = a.kid
          MINUS
          SELECT k.name, i.age, k.sex, i.present
          FROM   kids k
                 INNER JOIN intended_presents i ON k.sex = i.sex) a
), IntendedNotActual AS (
  SELECT name, age, sex, present intended
       , ID = Row_Number() OVER (Partition BY name, age ORDER BY present)
  FROM   (SELECT k.name, i.age, k.sex, i.present
          FROM   kids k
                 INNER JOIN intended_presents i ON k.sex = i.sex
                 INNER JOIN actual_presents a ON a.age = i.age AND k.sex = i.sex
          MINUS
          SELECT k.name, a.age, k.sex, a.present
          FROM   kids k
                 INNER JOIN actual_presents a ON k.Name = a.kid) i
)
SELECT Coalesce(a.name, i.name) name
     , Coalesce(a.age, i.age) age
     , Coalesce(a.sex, i.sex) sex
     , actual
     , intended
FROM   ActualNotIntended a
       FULL JOIN IntendedNotActual i ON a.name = i.name AND a.age = i.age 
             AND a.sex = i.sex AND a.id = i.id
```

- The `ActualNotIntended` get the gift received that were not intended, and add a row number
- The `IntendedNotActual` get the gift that were inteded but weren't received, and add a row number

  - The join with `actual_presents` is only to limit the age range of the kids, if you want to see the gift that they will receive in future years remove it
- The main query `FULL JOIN` the two CTE, the added `ID` of the two are used as a join helper to avoid row multiplication

Pretty straightforward

*** Edit by Spendius ***

Thanks for the reply, the double inner / outer join on intended_presents is what I was looking for all along. After translation on my DB it gives me:

```
select k.name, k.sex, ap.age, 
coalesce(ip2.present, ip.present) as intended_present, 
ap.present as actual_present
from kids k
inner join actual_presents ap on k.name = ap.kid
FULL OUTER JOIN intended_presents ip ON ap.age = ip.age AND k.sex = ip.sex AND ap.present = ip.present
inner join intended_presents ip2 on ap.age = ip2.age AND k.sex = ip2.sex 
WHERE  k.name IS NOT NULL and ap.age is not null
AND  (ip2.Present = ap.present OR ip.Present IS NULL) order by k.name, ap.age;

NAME  | S | AGE | INTENDED_PRESENT | ACTUAL_PRESENT
------+---+-----+------------------+------------------
Alice | F |   5 | Drum             | Drum
Alice | F |   5 | Doll             | Doll
Alice | F |   6 | Orange           | Orange
Alice | F |   6 | Poney            | Poney
Bob   | M |   5 | Car              | Car
Bob   | M |   5 | Itchy sweater    | Itchy sweater
Bob   | M |   6 | Soldier          | Soldier
Bob   | M |   6 | Coloring book    | Coloring book
Carol | F |   5 | Doll             | Trumpet
Carol | F |   5 | Doll             | Car
Carol | F |   5 | Drum             | Car
Carol | F |   5 | Drum             | Trumpet
Carol | F |   6 | Poney            | Poney
Dave  | M |   5 | Itchy sweater    | Soldier
Dave  | M |   5 | Car              | Coloring book
Dave  | M |   5 | Itchy sweater    | Coloring book
Dave  | M |   5 | Car              | Soldier
Dave  | M |   6 | Soldier          | Car
Dave  | M |   6 | Coloring book    | Car
Dave  | M |   6 | Soldier          | Itchy sweater
Dave  | M |   6 | Coloring book    | Itchy sweater
Dave  | M |   6 | Soldier          | Puppy

NAME  | S | AGE | INTENDED_PRESENT | ACTUAL_PRESENT
------+---+-----+------------------+-----------------
Dave  | M |   6 | Coloring book    | Puppy

23 rows selected.
```

Which indeed duplicates the rows when actual / intended don't match.
I like your suggestion of list aggregate, but unfortunately doesn't seem available on 10g. It would give me the following output, which could be acceptable:

```
NAME  | S | AGE | INTENDED_PRESENT      | ACTUAL_PRESENT
------+---+-----+-----------------------+--------------
Alice | F |   5 | Drum                  | Drum
Alice | F |   5 | Doll                  | Doll
Alice | F |   6 | Orange                | Orange
Alice | F |   6 | Poney                 | Poney
Bob   | M |   5 | Car                   | Car
Bob   | M |   5 | Itchy sweater         | Itchy sweater
Bob   | M |   6 | Soldier               | Soldier
Bob   | M |   6 | Coloring book         | Coloring book
Carol | F |   5 | Doll;Drum             | Trumpet
Carol | F |   5 | Doll;Drum             | Car
Carol | F |   6 | Poney                 | Poney
Dave  | M |   5 | Itchy sweater;Car     | Soldier
Dave  | M |   5 | Itchy sweater;Car     | Coloring book
Dave  | M |   6 | Soldier;Coloring book | Car
Dave  | M |   6 | Soldier;Coloring book | Itchy sweater
Dave  | M |   6 | Soldier;Coloring book | Puppy

    16 rows selected.
```

Comment: I had the same problem on Fiddle hence I also had to translate.

Comment: That's perfect, you nailed it ! Editing my original post with your solution. Thanks a lot for your time & effort. I'll also add the function-based view code, so you can see what kind of monster you protected me from :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem here lies in your data model. You don't have an age for any child in the kids table so you only have the sex to tie tables together. Therefore what you get is all possible combinations of intended and actual presents for each child because the number of presents intended for a child of a given age and sex is not necessarily the number of presents they actually receive.

Age isn't really appropriate in the actual_presents tables at all, that should merely be a link between a kid and a present. The problem you will have with your current design is that there is no way for you to produce a list of what presents each child is eligible to receive based on age and sex because you have no tie to the age of the child, you have merely repeated the present's intended target age in two different tables. If I have understood your requirements, and if you are able to change the design at all I'd suggest something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE kids(KidID number, Name varchar2(30), Sex varchar2(1), Age number);
CREATE TABLE presents(PresentID number, TargetAge number, Sex varchar2(1), Present varchar2(30));
CREATE TABLE  actual_presents(ActualPresentId number, KidID number, PresentID number);
```

This would then allow you to store the kids details like this:

```
insert into kids(KidID, Name, Sex, Age) values (1, 'Alice','F', 6);
insert into kids(KidID, Name, Sex, Age) values (2, 'Bob','M', 7);
insert into kids(KidID, Name, Sex, Age) values (3, 'Carol','F', 5);
insert into kids(KidID, Name, Sex, Age) values (4, 'Dave','M', 5);

insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (1, 5,'F', 'Drum');
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (2, 6,'F', 'Orange');
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (3, 5,'M', 'Itchy sweater');
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (4, 6,'M', 'Coloring book');        
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (5, 7,'M', 'Trumpet');
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (6, 7,'M', 'Apple');
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (7, 5,'F', 'Doll');
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (8, 6,'F', 'Pony');
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (9, 5,'M', 'Car');
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (10, 6,'M', 'Soldier');
insert into presents(PresentID, TargetAge, sex, present) values (11, 7,'F', 'Puppy');

insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (1, 1, 7);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (2, 1, 8);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (3, 2, 9);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (4, 2, 10);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (5, 3, 9);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (6, 3, 8);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (7, 4, 10);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (8, 4, 9);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (9, 1, 1);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (10, 1, 2);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (11, 2, 3);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (12, 2, 4);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (13, 3, 5);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (14, 4, 4);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (15, 4, 3);
insert into actual_presents(ActualPresentID, KidID, PresentID) values (16, 4, 11);
```

Now you need to have two queries really (and this applies whether you change your table structure or note): One which shows the presents that a child could receive for their age and gender and one to show what they actually got.

```
/*Possible presents per child based on gender and age*/
select k.name, k.sex S, k.age KidAge, p.Present
from kids k
inner join presents p
on p.targetage = k.age
and p.sex = k.sex
order by k.name asc;

/*Actual presents received by each child*/
select k.name, k.sex S, k.age KidAge, p.TargetAge, p.present
from Kids k
inner join actual_presents ap
on ap.KidID = k.KidID
inner join presents p
on p.PresentID = ap.PresentID
Order by k.name asc;
```

Does that make sense? Apologies for any type or formatting mistakes, I was doing this in SQL Server when I should really have been working!

Comment: I think it's all Ok with data model because children grows. E.g. Alice got an Orange when she was 5 years old and got a Doll one year later when she was 6 years old. On the other hand, report format are bad, but I saw such type of requirements several times in accountancy reports. It can be done by one relatively complex query with outer joins. I'll try to answer later because I don't have access to DB at the moment.

Comment: I see what you're saying but the impression i got was that it was the age the present was intended for in both columns, but it wasn't very clear so i could well be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll check your datamodel tomorrow and see whether I could make that work.

Comment: Do note that i made an assumption about the age columns that may be wrong. But its worth a thought (as is the other answer which i believe works with your existing model). Also, those id columns i added would need sequences to prevent you having to insert the values yourself.